# SPI Communication between ESP32S3

Tags: esp32, spi, arduino-esp32

I have two Esp32S3-WROOM-1 DevKits and I'm trying to communicate both with SPI, one slave and other master. I'm using Arduino IDE to do it.

I am connecting the wires like this:

| Master | Slave |
| --- | --- |
| PIN9/GPIO10 - CS | PIN9/GPIO10 - CS |
| PIN10/GPIO11 - MOSI | PIN10/GPIO11 - MOSI |
| PIN11/GPIO12 - SCK | PIN11/GPIO12 - SCK |
| PIN12/GPIO13 - MISO | PIN12/GPIO13 - MISO |

The codes I'm using:

[slave](/questions/tagged/slave)

```
#include <SPI.h>

volatile bool receivedFlag = false;
volatile byte receivedData = 0;

static const int spiClk = 1000000;

void IRAM_ATTR ssInterrupt() {
  if (digitalRead(SS) == LOW) {
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
    receivedData = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    receivedFlag = true;
    SPI.endTransaction();
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SS), ssInterrupt, FALLING);
  SPI.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS); // Inicia o SPI como slave
}

void loop() {
  if (receivedFlag) {
    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.println(receivedData);
    receivedFlag = false;
  }
}
```

[master](/questions/tagged/master)

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define SS_PIN 10

static const int spiClk = 1000000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SS_PIN, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS);
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(SS_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x45);
  digitalWrite(SS_PIN, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();

  delay(1000);
}
```

With Serial Monitor on Slave it just show `Received: 0`.

Can somebody help me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: In SPI Slave, SCK, SS, and MOSI are INPUT, and MISO is OUTPUT, so you can't use SPI.begin() to initialise the interface (it was for Master only). Slave does not control the clock, Master does, so spiClk and SPI.beginTransaction() are irrelevant for Slave.  For ESP32, I would suggest to take a look at [ESP32SPISlave](https://github.com/hideakitai/ESP32SPISlave) library by Hideakitai.